# Snakemake: How to use config file efficiently

Tags: indexing, config, wildcard, expand, snakemake

I'm using the following config file format in **snakemake** for a some sequencing analysis practice (I have loads of samples each containing 2 fastq files:

```
samples:
Sample1_XY:
    - fastq_files/SRR4356728_1.fastq.gz
    - fastq_files/SRR4356728_2.fastq.gz
Sample2_AB:
    - fastq_files/SRR6257171_1.fastq.gz
    - fastq_files/SRR6257171_2.fastq.gz
```

I'm using the following rules at the start of my pipeline to run fastqc and for alignment of the fastqc files:

```
import os
# read config info into this namespace
configfile: "config.yaml"

rule all:
    input:
    expand("FastQC/{sample}_fastqc.zip", sample=config["samples"]),
    expand("bam_files/{sample}.bam", sample=config["samples"]),
    "FastQC/fastq_multiqc.html"

rule fastqc:
    input:
        sample=lambda wildcards: config['samples'][wildcards.sample]
    output:
        # Output needs to end in '_fastqc.html' for multiqc to work
        html="FastQC/{sample}_fastqc.html",
        zip="FastQC/{sample}_fastqc.zip"
    params: ""
        wrapper:
        "0.21.0/bio/fastqc"

rule bowtie2:
    input:
         sample=lambda wildcards: config['samples'][wildcards.sample]
    output:
         "bam_files/{sample}.bam"
    log:
         "logs/bowtie2/{sample}.txt"
    params:
         index=config["index"],  # prefix of reference genome index (built with bowtie2-build),
    extra=""
         threads: 8
    wrapper:
         "0.21.0/bio/bowtie2/align"

 rule multiqc_fastq:
    input:
         expand("FastQC/{sample}_fastqc.html", sample=config["samples"])
    output:
         "FastQC/fastq_multiqc.html"
    params:
    log:
         "logs/multiqc.log"
    wrapper:
         "0.21.0/bio/multiqc"
```

My issue is with the fastqc rule.

Currently both the fastqc rule and the bowtie2 rule create one output file generated using two inputs `SRRXXXXXXX_1.fastq.gz` and `SRRXXXXXXX_2.fastq.gz`.

I need the fastq rule to generate two files, a separate one for each of the `fastq.gz` files but I'm unsure how to index the config file correctly from the fastqc rule input statement, or how to combine the the expand and wildcards commands to solve this. I can get an individual fastq file by adding `[0]` or `[1]` to the end of the input statement, but not both run individually/separately.

I've been messing around trying to get the correct indexing format to access each file separately. The current format is the only one I've managed that allows `snakemake -np` to generate a job list.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about using `fastq_files/SRR` instead of `fastq_files/SRR_[1|2].fastq.gz` in config file, and be explicit about `1` and `2` in rules' input and output?

Comment: Hi JeeYem, thanks for your suggestion. I tried this but it doesn't work as my file names are a bit more complex than what my original post said, and I have about 50 fastq files in total with unique fastq names and unique samples names. I have amended this now. I also tried adding `[0|1]` at the end of my fastqc input statement but it only ran the `SRRXXXXXXX_2 files`. If I use `[0]` or `[1]` separately I get each individual file, but I need a way for both to run in a separate instance of the rule. Hopefully the amended question makes the issue clear now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears each sample would have two fastq files, and they are named in format `***_1.fastq.gz` and `***_2.fastq.gz`. In that case, config and code below would work.

config.yaml:

```
samples:
    Sample_A: fastq_files/SRR4356728
    Sample_B: fastq_files/SRR6257171
```

Snakefile:

```
# read config info into this namespace
configfile: "config.yaml"
print (config['samples'])

rule all:
    input:
        expand("FastQC/{sample}_{num}_fastqc.zip", sample=config["samples"], num=['1', '2']),
        expand("bam_files/{sample}.bam", sample=config["samples"]),
        "FastQC/fastq_multiqc.html"

rule fastqc:
    input:
        sample=lambda wildcards: f"{config['samples'][wildcards.sample]}_{wildcards.num}.fastq.gz"
    output:
        # Output needs to end in '_fastqc.html' for multiqc to work
        html="FastQC/{sample}_{num}_fastqc.html",
        zip="FastQC/{sample}_{num}_fastqc.zip"
    wrapper:
        "0.21.0/bio/fastqc"

rule bowtie2:
    input:
         sample=lambda wildcards: expand(f"{config['samples'][wildcards.sample]}_{{num}}.fastq.gz", num=[1,2])
    output:
         "bam_files/{sample}.bam"
    wrapper:
         "0.21.0/bio/bowtie2/align"

rule multiqc_fastq:
    input:
        expand("FastQC/{sample}_{num}_fastqc.html", sample=config["samples"], num=['1', '2'])
    output:
        "FastQC/fastq_multiqc.html"
    wrapper:
        "0.21.0/bio/multiqc"
```

Comment: Hi JeeYem, many thanks for this. It has worked a treat. I think your structuring of the config file is a much more efficient than mine.